# Can a three way switch control two lights that have no connection?

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

Our contractor added a light at the bottom and top of the basement steps, each on separate switches. The top light is on a three-way switch with one of the switches right next to the switch for the bottom light. Can the bottom light be wired to be part of that three-way switch instead? Walls and everything are all closed up already so can't run anymore wires. I see typically you would have at least one wire connecting the two lights.

EDIT:

Adding pictures, also since it didn't make sense to have the bottom light on  its own switch, they wired it to a different set of lights which happen to also be on a three way. Hope the pictures are clear enough, didn't want to mess anything up pulling to far out.

This is the set of switches in the basement. Left is the threeway for the top light, right is the three way that includes the bottom light and the main lights in the basement.
[image]

Side view of the three way switch for the top light.
[image]

Side view of the three way switch the bottom light is hooked up to.
[image]

Side view of the three way switch at the top of the steps.
[image]

EDIT #2: More requested pictures of inside the box

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The 3-way arrangement is required by Code.  It sounds like the "top light" *is* your official stairway light for purposes of Code compliance.  So you want the switches controlling the top light to operate the bottom light, and eliminate the switch which currently controls it???  Can you get photos of the wiring inside each switch box (DO NOT unhook any wires, and we need photos looking into the back of the box).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine yes that's correct.

Comment: If your panel is in the basement like many homes with basements it is a possibility, with the 2 boxes adjacent it might be possible but there is not enough information, if your contractor suggested this I would say sure, at any level more investigation is needed

Comment: @riotburn -- can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: added pictures.

Comment: I can see green insulation on a wire in the 1st and 3rd pictures. That's a pointer toward there being conduit, as otherwise the ground would be bare in a cable installation (though insulated wire _could_ be used as a pigtail, it's less likely). Please gently pull the switches further out of the boxes and take pictures of the inside of the boxes, especially showing where the wiring leaves the box. If the contractor did a proper job of wiring, you won't disconnect anything. If he didn't, have him fix it before you finish paying.

Comment: @FreeMan it's bx cable, is that the same as conduit?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I'm not familiar with the various metal-clad cables. I don't think that the cable itself can be used as the ground, thus the green-insulated ground wire.

Comment: @FreeMan added pics inside the box.

Comment: I will leave it to the electricians to pass final judgement, but it appears that someone has remarked the green ground wire with red in order to use it as a hot or, perhaps, a traveler. AIUI, the ground wire should _never_ be reused/remarked for any purpose. Again, I could be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible wiring configurations here that would all be code-compliant. There are two possible situations where this may be easy to do:

##### Conduit

Unlikely. Most houses in the US are wired with cables. But if it turns out you have conduit then this is definitely fixable, though the details will vary a bit depending on the existing configuration.

##### 3-Way Switched Hot in Bottom Box

Note that this is based on the two light fixtures being on the same circuit (one breaker turns off both lights). If that is not the case then the wiring gets a little trickier.

The 3-way switches could be wired a few different ways:

- Power in at bottom, out at top and on to light
- Power in at top, loops back from bottom to top and on to light
- Power in at top, out at bottom and on to light
- Power in at bottom, loops back from top to bottom and on to light

In the first two cases, the *switched hot* wire goes straight from the top 3-way switch to the light fixture. In that case, there is no easy way to simply rearrange things in the switch boxes to make this work the way you want it to.

However, in the last two cases, the *switched hot* wire is present in the bottom 3-way switch box. If it receives power in the same box (i.e., power in at bottom box for both lights) then you can remove the non-3-way switch and connect the switched hot wire from the non-3-way switch to the switched hot wire coming from the 3-way switches and remove or cap (depends on how things are wired up) the hot wire from the non-3-way switch. However, if it is a switch loop, where power goes to the light fixture box (but doesn't connect to the light fixture) first and then down to the switch and back up to the light fixture then things are a bit more complicated.

**Pictures of switch boxes needed to figure out the actual situation.**

Comment: I would agree with your conduit statement but not enough information for the others

Comment: @EdBeal You may be right. Key is to see pictures to know what is really there.

Comment: Added pictures. Thanks for the responses so far.